# array minus average put into another array?

Tags: c++

i have no clue how to to start this function.

i wanted the value in the array to subtract from the average to produce the new array.

example:

```
1 2 3 old array
avg 2
new array -1 0 1
```

had a program earlier and couldnt run it because of errors.

can anyone give me a hint?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 100;
void readdata (double [], int &);
double findaverage (double [], int);
void howfaraway (double [], int);

int main()
{
    int n;
    double avg;
    double mark[SIZE];

    readdata(mark, n);
    avg = findaverage(mark, n);
    cout << avg;
    return 0;
}

void readdata(double numbers[], int&n)
{
    cout << "Enter the size> ";
    cin >> n;
    for (int count = 0; count < n; count++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the integer> ";
        cin >> numbers[count];
    }
    return;
}

double findaverage (double p[], int n)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count < n; count++)
        sum = sum + p[count];

    return (double) sum / n;
}

void howfaraway (double r[], double s[], int n)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < n; count++)

}
```

Comment: What are the errors? Do you expect people to debug it for you?

Answer (score 1):

I'll write some psuedocode:

```
length = lengthOf(oldarray);
newarray = new array[length]
avg=sum(oldarray)/length;


for(i=0; i<length; i++){
    newarray[i]=oldarray[i]-avg;
}

return newarray;
```

something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote something in your code. I hope this help:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
const int SIZE = 100;

//Variables here
int n;
double avg, numbers[SIZE];

//Functions here
void readdata ();
double findaverage ();
void howfaraway ();

int main()
{
    readdata(); // Read the input and calculate the avg.
    cout << "This is the Average: " << avg << endl; // Printing the avg
    cout << "This is the new array: "; 
    howfaraway(); // Printing the new array
    return 0;
}

void readdata()
{
    cout << "Enter the size: ";
    cin >> n;
    avg = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the integer: ";
        cin >> numbers[i];
        avg += numbers[i]; // Getting the total sum
    }
    if(n > 0)
        avg /= n; // Getting the avg
}

void howfaraway()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << numbers[i] - avg << " "; // Printing each new element
    cout << endl;
}
```